# Build Linq query in umbraco

Tags: c#, linq, umbraco

I am building a web service in C# using Umbraco's uQuery that takes 2 parameters and returns a JSON serialized string containing a list of search results.

I pass in a string array containing the tags for my search e.g. ["red", "blue"]

```
public string GetResultsHttp(string[] tags)
{
    IEnumerable<Node> nodes;

    // first get all nodes that are of the right content type
    nodes = uQuery.GetNodesByType("MyPage");

    // if tags are passed in then limit the results to those tags
    if (tags.Length > 0)
    {
        nodes = nodes.Where(n => tags.Contains(n.Parent.GetProperty("tags").Value));
    }

    // return the node list as a serialized string

}
```

So far so good and that works to return results that contain any of my tags.

now I want to limit the results by date. The dates array looks like this ["201410", "201411"] so it's year followed by month.

I want to further limit my result set to those results that have a myDate property where the month and year matches any of the months and years in my date array.

So my code becomes this:

```
public string GetResultsHttp(string[] tags, string[] dates)
{
    IEnumerable<Node> nodes;

    // first get all nodes that are of the right content type
    nodes = uQuery.GetNodesByType("MyPage");

    // if tags are passed in then limit the results to those tags
    if (tags.Length > 0)
    {
        nodes = nodes.Where(n => tags.Contains(n.Parent.GetProperty("tags").Value));
    }

    if (dates.Length > 0)
    {
        // the format of the incoming date
        string formatString = "yyyyMM";

        foreach (string dateTag in dates)
        {
            DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(dateTag, formatString, null);
            nodes = nodes.Where(n => (dt.Month.Equals(n.GetProperty<DateTime>("myDate").Month)) && (dt.Year.Equals(n.GetProperty<DateTime>("myDate").Year)));
        }
    }

    // return the node list as a serialized string

}
```

The above obviously works fine for 1 date, but if I pass in 2 it stands to reason that one page can't have 2 dates.

Also, I'm sure there is a much simpler way of achieving this :)

Thanks
Travis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently your query is ensuring that the date is equal to *All* of the dates in `dates`.  You want it to filter where `Any` of the dates are in `dates`.

```
var nodes= uQuery.GetNodesByType("MyPage")
    .Where(n => tags.Contains(n.Parent.GetProperty("tags").Value)
    .Where(n => dates.Any(dateString => 
        DatesAreEqual(dateString, n.GetProperty<DateTime>("myDate"));
```

(`DatesAreEqual` can contain all of the logic for comparing the dates, rather than trying to inline all of the parsing/comparing.)